# VSCode JavaScript autocompletion turns "this" into "globalThis"

Tags: javascript, this, visual-studio-code

VSCode autocompletion recently started to turn "this" into "globalThis" while in a JavaScript file.

[image: this turns to globalThis]

This is very annoying, each time I want to write "this.something" I need to ctrl+z my way out of an unwanted "globalThis.something".
I don't want to disable the whole JavaScript autocompletion though, I just need to turn it off for this particular word.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Surely this doesn't happen everywhere? Where specifically are you typing when it happens? Also, have you checked that it's not because of one of your extensions (by turning them all off and replicating it)?

Comment: What version of VSCode? I'm not seeing this in v1.40.1.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It happens anywhere in a JS file. Even an empty one. Also, I tried with all my extensions disabled as you suggested, but nothing changed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Since you're not seeing this, it must be coming from my settings. I've tried on another machine and even if I could see the "globalThis" suggestion, the "this" completion acted as expected.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was caused by the fact that I had disabled the "Show Keywords" option. Thus, the `this` suggestion didn't came up when I typed "this".

Solved it by re-enabling the option.

[image]